# c++ errors with ostream

Tags: c++, ostream

Hi im getting these errors in my code regarding my function that uses an ostream object.

```
EAN.cpp:151:54: error: no match for âoperator<<â in â(& std::operator<< [with _CharT = char, 
_Traits = std::char_traits<char>]((* & os), 
std::setw(17)))->std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
_Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>,
std::basic_ostream<_CharT, 
_Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>](std::right) << EAN::toStrWithStyle(((char*)(& outputEAN)))â
```

Here is the member function prototype in the header file:

```
void display(std::ostream& os) const;
```

And here is the function with the problem:

```
void EAN::display(std::ostream& os) const
{
  char outputEAN[17];

  os << setw(17) << right << toStrWithStyle(outputEAN) << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix these errors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `toStrWithStyle` return?

Comment: `void` ? - here is your bug

Comment: Here is an example of the display function being used in the main.     ean[i].display(std::cout);
And yea, I just realized my toStrWithStyle has void return type.  I meant to have toStrWithStyle take in a pointer to a char* as a parameter and it just changes that.

Comment: if `toStrWithStyle` modifies string on input then its better to return new modified string as std::string. You can also return pointer to outputEAN from that function, but you must be sure to not write outside its buffer, at least pass array size and check bounds while modifing string in `toStrWithStyle`- but IMO thats unnecessary risk.

Comment: K yea, the problem was with toStryWithStyle having no return type.  I changed up the display function a bit based on that and now it works.  Thanks for all the help everyone!  @marcin_j i would have done it exactly as you have said if it weren't for the specific instructions given my assignment :(

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so this does not show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*since nobody is posting correct answer to show that this has been solved*

Your function

```
void display(std::ostream& os) const;
```

should return something to print out; for example `char *`

```
char * display(std::ostream& os) const;
```

when using `<<` operator, the function you are using `toStrWithStyle` should return something to be printed on the screen; so about any basic type would at least give you an output. In this case `string` or `char *` will do just fine.